# Django - Searching by first name or last name with postgres - use gin index?

Tags: django

Basic search functionality, search using first or last or both names.

Model has first/last fields.

Ideas are to just search by first, search by last, join results.

Another would be to use a gin index on each, do the same, and order by similarity (slow?).

Perhaps even concatenate the two things, use a gin index on that, and order by similiarity. Is that possible without having the change the models?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Q` object to chain queries.

`from django.db.models import Q`

`User.objects.filter(Q(fname__startswith='foo') |      Q(lname__startswith='foo'))`

This would do OR.

Comment: This doesn't really handle structuring/ordering the output, though right? Like if we had 'foo'-> abbbbbbfoo, cccccfoo, dddddddddddddfoo, ..., foo, it might not show the actual match or closest match til result 300 or something right?

Comment: Then you can use `__contains` instead of `__startswith` to do `LIKE %q%` sql statement.